# LCD Screen laggy and ghosting following water damage - what to do now

Tags: laptop, macbook, lcd, water-damage

A friend of mind spilled water on his screen. After letting it dry out for a few days, we turned it on. Turns out, the screen is damaged and is now laggy and there is a trail whenever any motion occurs.

This is a Macbook and naturally, Apple store always costs a lot.

What to do now? Preferably a solution that won't cost.

Edit: video display of issue: http://sendvid.com/32qb5y29

Comment: Try plugging it to an external screen and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Your options are to replace the screen yourself or at a small repair shop, or get an external screen like the comment says and call it your new desktop computer.

If you want to get the screen replaced, find a used one on Ebay and buy the parts before you go to the shop to save money.